# how to disable page slide up when keyboard shows on windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, textbox, keyboard, focus

How can I disable the sliding effect on Windows Phone 8 when a user tap on textbox?
I've already resized the content on focus and lost focus having the title fixed, but however if i tap the last texbox the page slides up a little...
This is a way to completely disable this effect?

Thanks all

Comment: is the 'last' textbox is placed in a position that overlaps with keyboard?

Comment: yes it is a scrollview so if the user tap the textbox in the bottom of the page the page slides up. I have already handled the risize of the scrollview when the keyboard shows up (with focus events) but if I tap the textview on the bottom the page slides up.